# How can create dynamic fields in Laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i need create a few fields dynamic in my model from other model, por example i have one model to properties table y other to properties rules, so how can join properties rules with properties table. other exmaple with code

```
 class Properties extends Model{
   protected $table = 'properties';
 }

 class PropertyRules extends Model{
   protected $table = 'properties_rules'
 }


  $properties = Properties::all();
  //i hope something like that

  $properties = [
     'id'=>1234,
     'name'=>'Property Name',
     'checkIn'=>'10:00',//come from propertiesRules
     'checkOut'=>'14:00',//come from propertiesRules
  ];
```

I do not want to use a foreign key to that, I won't join these fields as come from properties table

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand. Maybe if you stated in more details what you are trying to accomplish and why, we would be able to provide more useful answers.

Comment: Ok sorry, I'm a beginner with the English, so I need something like that the $casts = [] but I want to create fields dynamic with values come other tables, the reason es because some fields are used in a lot of places in the backend, so I want to make this change only in the Model and this change can be used by default in all request for that Model.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need an actual foreign key, but you need a way to link both tables and you need to define a relationship between the models.

Then you can achieve something similar to

```
$properties = App\Properties::with('PropertyRules')->get();
```

Please read: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yeah, i know but that instruction is not exactly what I need it, because that value will be arriving in frontend as $properties = [ .id=>123,name=>Name, propertyRules=>[ id = id,etc] ]

Comment: i need that the Properties Model can take fields of propertiesRules and theses fields can be used as if the were Properties model

Comment: OK I get it now, you could try using a join.

Comment: ok but how can do? you can give me any example please or any refer. Please

Comment: You can use query builder methods with Eloquent models, check https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries. This is how you can use it: https://www.larashout.com/using-joins-in-laravel-eloquent-queries

Comment: Ok thanks for take you time to help me. But i need something like that a mutator, i mean to theses field ca be used by default in all requests.

Comment: maybe that is impossible, i don't know